# Nextpeer Advanced integration using cocos2D for Android & ios

Tags: android, ios

Recently i started working on Multiplayer games using Nextpeer SDK integration with cocos2D game engine for both Android and ios. I stuck at advanced integration part(communicating with live players and showing them in the screen). Please share some sample projects if you have. I don't want to do it in cocos2D-X.

Answer (score 0):

Nextpeer Cocos2d-x's [UFO-RUN sample](https://nextpeer.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV/How+to+Make+a+Game+Like+Fun+Run+using+Nextpeer) can be easily converted to Cocos2d.
Please take a closer look there.